# Посчитать количество строк с условиям из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Помогите пожалуйста.

Есть таблица с Актерами (`name`), с фильмами (`title`), и с информацией о том в каком фильме какой актер играл (`cast_info`).

Мне нужно посчитать в скольких фильмах снялся актер.
Я пишу

```
select count(1)
 FROM from cast_info 
where person_id=(select id from name where name like ('Depp, Johnny'))
```

нахожу все фильмы и сериалы где он снимался.

А в таблице `title`есть столбец `kind_id` которая указывает на то что это — фильм, сериал, тв шоу и т.п.

Я хочу поставить условие что бы считались только фильмы, не сериалы и прочее. Это `kind_id=1`.

Я по разному пробовал, но последнее вот

```
select count(1)
FROM (
  select
  from cast_info c, title t
  where person_id=(select id from name where name like ('Depp, Johnny'))
    and t.kind_id=1
) AS pss
```

Но считает все строки 565 470 048.

Как поставить условие?

Comment: Не указано условие соединения таблиц `cast_info` и `title`

Comment: В таблице cast_info есть столбец movie_id и он равен id в таблице title. Самой связи в ER диаграмме нет.

Comment: Этот факт (`cast_info.movie_id = title.id`) у вас никак не отражен в sql-запросе, Поэтому и получаете больше строк чем нужно

Comment: Cпасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(1)
FROM
(select
from cast_info c, title t
where person_id=(select id from name where name like ('Depp, Johnny')) 
and c.movie_id = t.id 
and t.kind_id=1) AS pss
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вместо неявный соединений SQL-92 (`select * from a, b where a.id=b.id and ...`) лучше использовать явный join (`select * from a inner join b on a.id=b.id where ...`) Это позволяет семантически отделать условие соединения от условия отбора

Answer (score 0):

Связи между таблицами не прописаны, но если без вложенных запросов, то примерно будет так:

```
create table actors(
 actor_id integer,
 name text
 
)

create table titles(
 title_id integer,
 name text,
 kind_id integer
)

create table cast_info(
 actor_id integer,
 title_id integer
)

insert into actors select 1, 'actor1'
insert into actors select 2, 'actor2'
insert into actors select 3, 'actor3'
insert into titles select 1, 'title1', 1
insert into titles select 2, 'title2', 1
insert into titles select 3, 'title3', 1
insert into titles select 4, 'title4', 2
insert into cast_info select 1, 1
insert into cast_info select 1, 2
insert into cast_info select 1, 4
insert into cast_info select 2, 1
insert into cast_info select 2, 2

select
 a.actor_id,
 a.name,
 count(t.*)
from
 actors a
left join
 cast_info c
on
 c.actor_id = a.actor_id
left join
 titles t
on
 t.title_id = c.title_id
where
 a.name like ('actor1') and
 t.kind_id = 1
group by 
 a.actor_id, 
 a.name
```

Comment: Я добавил решение снизу, подсказали уже. Спасибо за отклик

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name.name, count(cast_info.*)
FROM name
LEFT JOIN cast_info ON name.id = cast_info.АктёрИД
WHERE name.name like ('Depp, Johnny')
GROUP BY name.name
```